# My bootstrap navbar can't fit on mobile

Tags: css, responsive-design

This is my page, the bootstrap navbar normal working on PC.
http://web.ntnu.edu.tw/~60132057A/MyTalk.php

But can't fit on mobile(as fig)

[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dc0KG.jpg)
I hardly try to fix the problem, but I can't make navbar fit PC and mobile sometime.

How to fix it?

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```css
<style> 
.div-left{margin:0 auto;text-align:left;width:540px;border:1px solid #FFF;} 
</style> 
<style scoped>
.container-fluid
{
  background-color: #78268c; 
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar-header > a:link,
.navbar-header > a:visited,
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:link,
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:visited
{
  color: #D4D4D4;
}

.navbar-header > a:hover,
.navbar-header > a:focus,
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:focus
{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #561b64; 
}
</style>
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body align="center">
    <br><!--不加上這個br的話，nav上面會有留白，但是原因不清楚-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <!--chrome還不支援style scoped這個語法-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/~60132057A/">LKY's space</a></li>
                <li><a href="/~60132057A/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/~60132057A/MyInfo.php">簡歷</a></li>
                <li><a href="/~60132057A/MyProject.php">作品</a></li>
                <li><a href="/~60132057A/MyCourse.php">課程</a></li>
                <li><a href="/~60132057A/MyTalk.php">嘴砲</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <h4>Fixed Navbar</h4>
    <br>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean the navbar overflows on layout. If so, Use **navbar-fixed** class instead of **navbar-fixed-top** class ( **`<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed">`** )

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```css
<style> 
.div-left{margin:0 auto;text-align:left;width:540px;border:1px solid #FFF;} 
</style> 
<style scoped>
.container-fluid
{
  background-color: #78268c; 
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar-header > a:link,
.navbar-header > a:visited,
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:link,
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:visited
{
  color: #D4D4D4;
}

.navbar-header > a:hover,
.navbar-header > a:focus,
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:focus
{
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #561b64; 
}
</style>
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body align="center">
    <br><!--不加上這個br的話，nav上面會有留白，但是原因不清楚-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">


    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed">
        <!--chrome還不支援style scoped這個語法-->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="/~60132057A/">LKY's space</a></li>
                <li><a href="/~60132057A/">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/~60132057A/MyInfo.php">簡歷</a></li>
                <li><a href="/~60132057A/MyProject.php">作品</a></li>
                <li><a href="/~60132057A/MyCourse.php">課程</a></li>
                <li><a href="/~60132057A/MyTalk.php">嘴砲</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <h4>Fixed Navbar</h4>
    <br>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bootstrap your objects implementing classes for each part

When bootstrapping, the entire width in full scale is 12 columns of width, and there are classes that will help you to make your objects and page to be responsive with minimal effort, check out this page, read and be patient :)

```
 http://getbootstrap.com/css/
```

Answer (score 0):

I fix by myself, add this.
But not perfect.

```css
.navbar-nav li{
            display: inline-block;
        }
```